# Why is this PNG converting to black JPG in imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I swear this image was properly converting to a white-background JPG with black line art. [Here is the original PNG](https://github.com/termsurf/file/blob/make/base/image/fire.png) (in case SE changes it when you upload). Here is what it looks like:

[image]

But this is the JPG I am seeing when I do `convert fire.png fire.jpg`:

[image]

Again, I had this working at some point, successfully converting this transparent PNG to a white-background JPG, using this exact PNG input image. But now it's not working. The only thing that I can think of that has changed is I have saved this in a GitHub branch, created a new GitHub branch, move the file in a new folder, commit, and merge back to the main branch. So perhaps there is some funkiness with the binary image changing in Git in some strange way?

Another thing is, could it have to do with the folders the images are in, or the file paths they are at?

```
convert ../external-directory/fire.png ./local-directory/fire.jpg
convert /absolute/path/fire.png ./local-directory/fire.jpg
convert "/absolute/path/fire.png" "./local-directory/fire.jpg"
```

I tried several combos with/without quoting and at different file paths, but no change.

Any idea what is wrong and how to fix it? Maybe I am losing my mind and because the image is transparent, that is what's causing problems. But I swear this was converting successfully before.

I am on a Mac M3 with ImageMagick 7.1.1-27.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the png. btw, you know you can do this type of simple conversion natively in macOS. I have several similar set up as Services in Automator, with key commands to launch & change any selected image.

Comment: That’s most likely because the PNG _is_ all black. Except for alpha transparency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember, ImageMagick always uses black as the default background if it cannot represent transparency. Specify a custom background color via `-background`:

```
magick convert foo.png -background "#ffffff" -alpha remove -quality 90 foo.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Several applications I'm using insist that this image is not a
legal PNG file, so it might be corrupted or of an exotic variant.
Anyway, I can't open it to check anything, except in the browser.

If the image uses transparency it will be removed leaving black.
You can change the color to anything you want:

```
convert image.png -background somecolor -flatten image.jpg
```